# MoviePy, using a gif as an ImageClip?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, gif, shapes, moviepy

Using a gif inside an ImageClip doesn't work, is it a normal behavior?

## The code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from moviepy.editor import *

video = VideoFileClip('./video.mp4')
watermark = (ImageClip("./my.gif")
                        .set_duration(10))

watermaked = CompositeVideoClip([video, watermark], size=video.size)
watermaked.write_videofile('./gif_output.mp4', fps=30, threads=1)
```

.

## The error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150) into shape (150,150,3)
```

.

## The stack error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gif_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    watermaked.write_videofile('./gif_output.mp4', fps=30, threads=1)
  File "<decorator-gen-51>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "<decorator-gen-50>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 137, in use_clip_fps_by_default
    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
  File "<decorator-gen-49>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 349, in write_videofile
    progress_bar=progress_bar)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 209, in ffmpeg_write_video
    fps=fps, dtype="uint8"):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 833, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 475, in generator
    frame = self.get_frame(t)
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in get_frame
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py", line 95, in get_frame
    return self.make_frame(t)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/compositing/CompositeVideoClip.py", line 110, in make_frame
    f = c.blit_on(f, t)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 611, in blit_on
    return blit(img, picture, pos, mask=mask, ismask=self.ismask)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/tools/drawing.py", line 45, in blit
    new_im2[yp1:yp2, xp1:xp2] = blitted
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150) into shape (150,150,3)
```

Answer (score 5):

**TL:DR,**

Gif are treated as video: VideoFileclip("image.gif") and not as ImageClip("image.gif").

## Working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from moviepy.editor import *

video = VideoFileClip('./video.mp4')
watermark = VideoFileclip("./image.gif")

watermaked = CompositeVideoClip([video, watermark], size=video.size)
watermaked.write_videofile('./gif_output.mp4', fps=30, threads=1)
```

Comment: This turns my transparent gif  into white background